# Automating a button click issue

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I'm having some trouble with automating a button test.
How can I automate a test with Java&Selenium to auto-click this following button?

```
<button class="btn btn-default primary-bg btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class= .btn btn-default primary-bg btn-lg']")).click();
```

What am I doing wrong? What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add ' after class=

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class=' .btn btn-default primary-bg btn-lg']")).click();
```

Or maybe

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default primary-bg btn-lg']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this button is this only one on page with this class:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn-default")).click();
```

If you have more buttons with same class:

```
List<WebElement> btnList =driver.findElements(By.className("btn-default")).click();
for(WebElement btn : btnList){
  if(btn.getText().equals("Submit"){
    btn.click();
  }
}
```